# String IndexOfAny function exception

Tags: c#, string

Why this code gives index out of range exception when I run it ?

```
class stringcodetesting 
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string t =  "  abcdefghigklmnopqrstuvwxyz" ;
        string c;
        char [] ar = { 'h', '1','2', '3','4'};

        c = "aarsa";              
        Console.WriteLine(t[t.IndexOfAny(ar,0,6)]);    
    }
}
```

but when the `string t value ="abcdefghigklmnopqrstuvwxyz"`  (without space in the beginning of the string ) it works correctly without exception.

Comment: `.IndexOfAny` returns -1. Besides that, what are you actually trying to achieve?

Answer (score 3):

Because within the first 6 characters ([`.IndexOfAny(..., 0, 6)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6wh7x3fs.aspx)) of `t` there's no occurence of any of the characters in `ar`. That is also reflected by the return value of `-1`, which means *no occurence found*.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, already answered above as to the reason, but here is a solution.

```
If(t.IndexOfAny(ar,0,6) >= 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(t[t.IndexOfAny(ar,0,6)]);
    }
Else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("No Match!");
    }
```